# keeping selected value in the dropdown after reloading the page in php

Tags: php, html

I have a dropdown in my form, In which data is being fetch from database, Problem is i want to keep the selected value in the dropdown if page reloads. Any help will be really appreciated.

Here is my code

```
 <select name="ans_type" class="select-form " onChange="checkAnswer(this.value)"             style="background-color: #fff !important;width:159px!important;">
        <option value="" style="color:#000">Select</option>
        <?php
        $sql = "select * from (table name)";
        $res = mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql);
        $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($res);
        if($numrows){
            while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($res)){
                if($ansTypeId == $obj->id){
                    echo '<option value="'.$obj->id.'" style="color:#000" selected>'.($obj->ans_type).'</option>';
                }
                else{
                    echo '<option value="'.$obj->id.'" style="color:#000">'.($obj->ans_type).'</option>';
                }   
            }   
        }
        ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Please, edit your code because we don't see anything. If you want help, help us to understand you.

Comment: Why you want to keep the selected value when page reloads. It's werid use case. I don't remember to see sucj approach like this before.

Comment: You could save the option value in your db when a user selects it, and read it from db when you load your page to select it again.

Comment: I want to store the selected value because i am doing form-validation, in my form if any mandatory text box is empty , error msg pops up and the same page reloads , so after reloading ,The value is not setting , so i have to enter the fields again n again

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
selected = '';
      if($ansTypeId == $obj->id){
                      $selected = "selected='selected'"; 
      }
echo '<option value="'.$obj->id.'" style="color:#000" $selected>'.
($obj->ans_type).'</option>';
```

Comment: Try this <?php $selected = '';
      if($ansTypeId == $obj->id){
                      $selected = "selected='selected'"; 
      }
echo '<option value="'.$obj->id.'" style="color:#000" '.$selected.'>'.
($obj->ans_type).'</option>';?>

Comment: I am getting this error "Trying to get property of non-object in D"

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
<select name="ans_type" class="select-form " onChange="checkAnswer(this.value)" style="background-color: #fff !important;width:159px!important;">
        <option value="" style="color:#000">Select</option>
        <?php
        $selectStr = '';
        $sql = "select * from (table name)";
        $res = mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql);
        $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($res);
        if($numrows){
            while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($res)){
                $selectStr = ($ansTypeId == $obj->id) ? 'selected' : '';
                echo '<option value="'.$obj->id.'" style="color:#000" '.$selectStr.'>'.($obj->ans_type).'</option>';
            }
        }
        ?>
</select>
```